# Body element showing behind Content Wrapper with a width of 100%

Tags: css, width, viewport

I have a contentWrapper class which contains all of the elements on my page. For some reason, the navigation takes up what appears to be 100% of the body and then some. I cannot however get the following elements, the slider and divs below, to stretch to fill the same width. There is always extra room to scroll to the right which displays the background color. I have made it pink in the fiddle its easy to see.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.contentWrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y26tqw/

Any suggestions? I feel like it could be an easy fix, deleting sections of the page at a time did not seem to remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like your .cycle-overlay is 100% wide and left is set to 20px. This is pushing everything over and revealing the background. Setting the width to 300px got rid of it for me.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whoacowboy/o5y26tqw/2/)

```
.cycle-overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I checked into it a bit more and you can keep the left position if you set the width.